# How to copy an SVG element of a HTML page into downloadable text file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, text

I build an SVG element from scratch into an HTML page using Javascript. Note that the SVG element contains only texts, whose typefaces come from the server using a "@font-face" declaration on the CSS file. So far, it's okay.
Now I want to copy the SVG element to a text file (myFile.svg), which can be downloaded from a button. I found a lot of tips for doing this, but not a really helpful one.
Did I look bad?

Answer (score 0):

to open new text file named as myFile.svg and past to it code from you svg. and save. example

```
<svg width="14" height="15" viewBox="0 0 14 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M13.8802  6.02104Z" fill="#656565"/>
</svg>
```